# Header wrapped over two lines with pgfplotstable

Tags: pgfplotstable

I have a table produced by pgfplotstable. I want to force two headers to wrap on two lines but I can't get it working.

This is in my script:

```
\documentclass{article}

% Set the values for the biblography
\usepackage[
    isbn=false,
    url=false,
    doi=false,
    eprint=false,
]{biblatex}

% For tables
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{caption}

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\pgfplotstableset{
    font={\small},
    empty cells with={--}, %  replace empty cells with ’--’
    every head row/.style={before row=\toprule,after row=\midrule},
    every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule}
}

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

%Set column width (This is my fix...)
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3.5pt}

% Create command for paragraph style (new line after)
\newcommand{\myparagraph}[1]{\paragraph{#1}\mbox{}\\}

\begin{document}


\myparagraph{paragraph}
Blalalala

% Add table
\begin{table}
\caption{My table}
\centering
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    columns/City/.style={string type},
    columns/Wrap it/.style={column type=|C},
    col sep=comma]{table.csv},
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

I got the error `Paragraph ended before \NC@find was complete.` before the `\end{table}` line.

This is my table.csv

```
City,Wrap it
London,12
Paris,12
Rome,323
```

I want the header "Wrap it" to be on two lines, so to reduce the width of only the second column.

Comment: Can you make a MWE with a few lines of data? It's not clear from what you have described.

Comment: Sorry what's a MWE?

Comment: Oops,sorry. That's a minimal working example that starts with `\documentclass{...}` all the way to `\end{document}`  that replicates the issue. Here is more info about [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)

Comment: Well, thank you for taking care of my misfortunes...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to either remove the argument from the column declaration or use `C{2.5em}`. Then your example works without any problems.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable,booktabs,array}

\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2.5em}}

\pgfplotstableset{
    font={\small},
    empty cells with={--}, %  replace empty cells with ’--’
    every head row/.style={before row=\toprule,after row=\midrule},
    every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{My table}
\centering
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    columns/City/.style={string type},
    columns/Wrap it/.style={column type=|C},
    col sep=comma]{
    City,Wrap it
    London,12
    Paris,12
    Rome,323
},
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]